# How to do hardware decoding of video on Android?

Tags: android, video, codec, hardware-acceleration

How does Android tablet PC hardware decode hd video? The CPU is arm. The hardware decoding in system should be with Mali module to do hard solution. But I don't know how to it. Anyone’s help is very appreciating.

Answer (score 2):

In Android 4.1 or later, use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API to encode or decode video from Java.

Mali is the GPU, but it doesn't contain a VDU (video decoder unit), that is chipset-specific for each SoC.  Chipset vendors like TI, QCOM etc each have their own, and they each provide their own OpenMAX (OMX) components to do this, and you will see some of those mentioned in the android adb logs.

Sample code: http://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/